# Json comparison

Tags: java, json, gson, jsonschema

I need some help. I have 2 json. Jsons have structure like following
Products:
[ {
     Productcode:alpha,
     Functions: [{
     FunctionCode:beta,
     Resources:[
      {Res1},
      {Res2}]
        }]
 }]

Now I have conditions, I want to compare them at resources level and see if the resource is present in json 2 only, its an addition, if the resource in json 1 only, its a deletion and if resources exist at both the places then its a modification. I also need to do following if functions has no resources then I need to send action as add otherwise as modify and same if for product node based if its already present or not.

So in short I have to compare two json and send their deltas to the other system with action attribute for all of them. Can someone please direct me on how to approach this?

Edit: Things I have tried so far:. 
I am using java. I tried using jsonpatch and gson but the results are not what I'm looking for as they tell me the difference but I need to put some logic based on the presence of resources on left and right json files Also, I need to make sure that product is sending ADD as action in case there is no child node and so is the case for functioncode

Comment: Using what language? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am using java. I tried using jsonpatch and gson but the results are not what I'm looking for as they tell me the difference but I need to put some logic based on the presence of resources on left and right json files Also, I need to make sure that product is sending ADD as action in case there is no child node and so is the case for functioncode

Comment: Please tag the question with all the relevant technology and also show what you tried in case it's fixable or extendable

Comment: If you know the structure of the 2 jsons ahead of time you could use GSON to turn them into java objects, then use logic to compare them and output a json as a result.